# How do I create a data source query to display a list of certain records?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a simple form where users can enter some data. 
The form collects my email automatically under 'email' field. 
On the page with this form I would like to have a table that displays only records that I have entered, or where email field is matching my own.
How do I build a datasource query to match my email and bind it to the table? Ideally I would like this table refreshed every time a new records (under my email) is created.

Comment: Depending on your needs from the model as a whole you can either implement model security for the load action and set it to just 'Owner' or to 'Owner or Roles'. Otherwise I suggest implementing in your datasource query script the following query `query.filters.email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail; return query.run()`.

Comment: Thank you. I may be missing a step. I have a datasource and query set. When I set table chart widget on the page it loads all records, not just those with my email.

Comment: I just realized I missed one item in that query, it should be `query.filters.email._equals = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); return query.run();`. I guess make that two, was missing the _equals part and the () at the end of getEmail.

Comment: Thank you again. That was it. It works! While I have you, is there a quick way to count the number of records in table?

Comment: It would only be a quick solution if you are not filtering your datasource based on user set filters. However once you introduce user filters that can be anything it becomes complicated very quickly because you have to 'copy' all filters in a calculated datasource server script that only returns your `.length` property of the records a query would return.

Comment: Is it possible in invert sorting by row number? That way at least a user can see the count of records at the top.

Comment: Realistically speaking that concept could very easily fail actually. Consider your setup for your key(row) field, although it is likely a number and auto incrementing, the chance for deletion of records in between is relatively high, so a row number of 1000 would not return the correct count if you have deleted records.

Comment: Ops, this is working but it's not updating the table when I mark a record. Is there a way to refresh the page on data change (in the form that's above it)?